# Zone "asia-east1-[abc]" increasingly hitting resources exhaustion

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We're based in Australia, so the logical zone for us to choose to run our Cloud Dataflow pipelines is one of the SEA zones i.e. asia-east1-x

For the last few days we've been getting an error that the the zone does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request:

> 2015-04-13T04:36:14.135Z: (87beb4ec714a2776): Workflow failed. Causes: (21d127c58eb9cdaf): Step setup_resource_global_gce_worker_pool2: Set up of resource global_gce_worker_pool failed Causes: (21d127c58eb9cf88): One or more operations had an error: 'operation-1428899724019-51393a4784539-e52869ff-98f5905a': 'The zone 'projects/[removed]/zones/asia-east1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or try again later.'

It's pretty clear what the problem is, but we're only requesting 5-10 instances in the worker pool - that's not really a large amount to request.

Why, in only the last few day, has this error started, and is it a known issue that will be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute Engine capacity stocks out from time-to-time based on demand and  newly arriving supply.  Like the message indicates, you can try another zone (like asia-east1-b) which may have capacity at this time.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Chambers. We're going to bake in some error handling logic to retry on a different zone if the resources cannot be allocated. However, just thought I would ask - is there anyway to specify that behaviour with the dataflow service via the SDK?

Comment: Yeah, the sdk REALLY needs a way to ask/reserve in a zone in a easy manner.  We're running 20-30 jobs at a time and when these sweeping zone outages hit for hours, it crushes our support lines.